# find() takes no keyword arguments - List comprehemsion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and am attempting a web scraping project. However, I'm completely stuck on creating a list which removes all excess chars around the text without it throwing back an error. Below is the code along with the error I keep getting, where am I going wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
page = requests.get("https://www.ufc.com/rankings")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
rankings = soup.find(class_ = "view-grouping-content")

ranking_names = [item.find(class_ = "views-row").get_text() for item in rankings]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liam/PycharmProjects/ufcrankingwebscraper/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    ranking_names = [item.find(class_ = "views-row").get_text() for item in rankings]
  File "/Users/liam/PycharmProjects/ufcrankingwebscraper/main.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    ranking_names = [item.find(class_ = "views-row").get_text() for item in rankings]
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" Well, the error is complaining about the line of code `anking_names = [item.find(class_ = "views-row").get_text() for item in rankings]`, and the error message says that `find() takes no keyword arguments`. The part of the line that involves `find` is `item.find(class_ = "views-row")`. The error message says that you cannot use this with the `find` method of `item`. So. Did you try to check what the type  of `item` is? (I.e., did you try checking what `rankings` contains?) Did you check the BeautifulSoup documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code below:

```
print([type(item) for item in rankings])
```

Produces the output below:

```
[<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>, <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>]
```

This means that your list comprehension contains two items.
The first item is of type `bs4.element.Tag`, which has a `find` method that behaves as you are expecting.
The second item is of type `bs4.element.NavigableString`, which also has a `find` method like all `str` objects, but this find method behaves differently from what you are expecting, hence the error.

The code block below will give you an output, but I am not sure if it is really what you are looking for. It gives you the first name in the first weight division.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.ufc.com/rankings")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
rankings = soup.find(class_ = "view-grouping-content")

ranking_name = rankings.find(class_ = "views-row").get_text()
    
print(ranking_name)
```

I have a feeling that you however want to get all the fighters in the first weight division.
You can get that by using the code block below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.ufc.com/rankings")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
rankings = soup.find(class_ = "view-grouping-content")

ranking_name_rows = rankings.find_all(class_ = "views-row")
    
ranking_names = [item.get_text().strip() for item in ranking_name_rows]
print(ranking_names)
```

Comment: ahh I see now, this makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!